# Atomic compareAndIncrement in HBase

Tags: java, hbase, atomic

Is it possible to increment columns in HBase based on some comparison operator atomically ?
Both increments and comparisons will be done on same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkAndIncrement method is not implemented yet in HBase. There's a ticket for it - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6712.

What's your use? Isn't it something you can do with checkAndPut ?

Comment: My use case is - I have two columns in my row. I want to increment one field and set second field's value if current value of second field is less than the value I am trying to set. Otherwise, none of them should be updated. I want increment and set to be atomic in nature.

Comment: So checkAndPut won't help you either as you can only test for value equality, not if it's smaller or bigger. I don't know of an atomic operation in HBase that will allow you to do that. (Unless you write your own in a co-processor).

Comment: I know this is an old question (nearly a year) - just wondering if there is a way to atomically test for checks other than equality yet?

Comment: Looks like it was added in new releases, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11796